# Ternary operator logic

Tags: c, numbers, ternary-operator

I need to convert a double number to an integer based on a condition, but when I use the ternary operator I get some weird results. I wrote this simple program to test my logic but I cannot understand what's going on.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  double n = 50.0;

  printf("%i\n", (int)n);

  printf("%i\n", ((1) ? (int)n : n));

  printf("%i\n", ((1) ? n : (int)n));

  printf("%i\n", ((0) ? (int)n : n));

  printf("%i\n", ((0) ? n : (int)n));

  return 0;
}
```

I expected to get the following output:

```
50
50
0
0
50
```

But the output I got was:

```
50
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: Protip: compile with warnings.

Comment: Your code is invalid. You can't print a `double` with `%i` format.

Comment: @Barmar I know that, and that's why i am trying to convert to an `int`, note that the first `printf` prints out the value correctly.

Comment: @RayToal great tip, I got warnings in the 4 last `printf`s, but not the first one. From what I understand, the first and the last ternary operator is returning a `double`, where it should be returning an ìnt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the 2nd and 3rd operands to the ternary operator have different types, they are automatically converted to the same type, using the [usual arithmetic conversions](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter2/expressions_and_arithmetic.html). So doing a cast on just one of the operands doesn't have the effect you expect -- `(int) n` will be cast back to `double` and that will be the type of the ternary expression.

This will then be passed to `printf`, and you'll get undefined behavior because you're trying to print a `double` using `%i` format, which expects an `int`.

If you want the type of the argument to depend on the condition, you need to use an ordinary `if`. For instance, this is what you were apparently trying to accomplish in your first ternary example:

```
if (1) {
    printf("%i\n", (int) n); // valid
} else {
    printf("%i\n", n); // invalid
}
```

Comment: I was not aware of the "usual arithmetic conversions". And I'm working on a larger program where I created a macro to do this for me, using the ternary operator to "return" the value, so doing an if statement was not an option (because I'm lazy). Anyway, I could just create an inline function, but I got so curious with this behaviour that I had to ask, since I didn't found anything when searching.

Comment: An inline function isn't any better, since it can only have one return type. The general point is that any expression has to have a type that's determined at compile time, it can't depend on a runtime condition.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. I just noticed that now when I was about to compile. I will rethink a little about this, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have tripped over two dark corners of the C language at once.

1. Given `double n`, the "[usual arithmetic conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic)" cause `(ANYTHING ? (int)n : n)` and `(ANYTHING ? n : (int)n)` to both have type `double`.  That is, if the `(int)n` branch is taken, the value `n` is converted to `int` *and then back to `double`*.
2. `printf("%i\n", (double)whatever)` provokes undefined behavior.  This is because `printf` relies on its format string to know the types of its variadic arguments.  If you tell it to print an `int` but you pass a `double` it will look in the wrong place for the value to print.

Because of (1), (2) affects all four of the `printf` statements containing a ternary expression, not just the ones where the cast-to-`int` branch was not taken.

I don't understand what you were trying to accomplish with `(condition ? (int)n : n)`, so I can't tell you what you should have done instead.

Comment: I'm using only `double` to represent numbers in my application, but I wanted to print an int when the number is truncated. Guess I will just use an if statement instead of the ternary operator. Thanks for the enlightment.

Comment: @GuilhermeNemeth I think you might be looking for [floor](http://linux.die.net/man/3/floor) or one of its relatives.

Answer (score 1):

In the standard for the 'conditional operator', it says:

> If both the second and third operands have arithmetic type, the result type that would be determined by the usual arithmetic conversions, were they applied to those two operands, is the type of the result.

Since you have `int` and `double` as the types, the result of the conditional is always `double`, so you get whatever garbage you get when you print it with the wrong format — which is invoking undefined behaviour and a bad idea